# Get foreground windows of windows explorer to retrieve the url

Tags: powershell

I think am close to the solution, or in the general ball park, but the way am calling the powershell might be part of the issue am calling the ps1 from a batch file, to

I want to have the user click a button and then have powershell get the url of the active window (EXPLORER.exe) - i did try to but the start/sleep command to check in the ISE but could get it to work :( could you help be out ?

Thank You

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Param(
)
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class UserWindows {
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
}
"@
try {
$ActiveHandle = [UserWindows]::GetForegroundWindow()
$Process | Select LocationURL| select -ExpandProperty LocationURL -First 1 | 
Tee-Object -Variable "dirvar"
} catch {
Write-Error "Failed to get active Window details. More Info: $_"
}
$dirvar1 = "$dirvar" -replace 'file:///', '' 
echo "$dirvar1"
Start-Process "Z:\30_Sysadmin\ADB_LOADER_DIR\ADBDIR.bat" "$dirvar1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going about it in a difficult way. There are helper functions. This lists all shell windows (Internet Explorer and Explorer windows). The object is an Internet Explorer object. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx.

This is VBScript but COM calls are identical across all languages.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
For Each window in AllWindows
    window.Navigate "c:\"
    msgbox window.locationURL
Next
```

Comment: i don't want to get all the windows but the active one eg. not the first one just the first one opened, thats where am having an issue

Comment: You go through all windows to find the one you want. This is basic programming skills.

Comment: No but that is a core technique of processing lists. You can't get the *first* one as Windows doesn't know which is the first one. One common technique is to do a series of linear steps, next is to process lists, then to walk trees.